# Able to authenticate with SSH with Github but somehow says "key is already in use"?

Tags: authentication, github, ssh, github-cli

I have two ssh keys i've created, first one for my personal use and
the second one which I just created for work/school.

When I log into using git CLI using SSH with the second SSH key, it says
that i have successfully logged in like below

```
$ winpty gh auth login
? What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
? You're already logged into github.com. Do you want to re-authenticate? Yes
? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations? SSH
? Upload your SSH public key to your GitHub account? C:\Users\dykim\.ssh\id_rsa.
pub
? Title for your SSH key: (GitHub CLI) second-key

? Title for your SSH key: future_proof
? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI? Login with a web browser

! First copy your one-time code: 0B1D-6370
Press Enter to open github.com in your browser...
✓ Authentication complete.
- gh config set -h github.com git_protocol ssh
✓ Configured git protocol
HTTP 422: Validation Failed (https://api.github.com/user/keys)
key is already in use
```

so somehow there  isn't a problem to authenticating.
But I am worried that this will somehow pop up later and be a problem later when I am
working on my future projects for work.

What can I do to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That seems similar to a pending reported issue #5299: "[Spurious auth error when SSH key is already registered on account](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5299)"

> ### Steps to reproduce the behavior
>
> - Run `gh auth login` and select an SSH key that is already registered with the account
> - Get the above error, even though the key will work correctly
>
> ### Expected vs actual behavior
>
> I think there are a couple of ways that the handling of already registered keys could be improved:
>
> - Given the CLI app is granted full permission over the user's registered SSH keys, it could presumably list the already registered ones first and only attempt to register a new key if it wasn't already registered.
>   Then the error would only occur if the key was registered on a different account (or you uploaded it via the web browser while also attempting to register the CLI app, which would be an odd thing to do)
> - Customise the error message when this step fails to say something like "key already in use (Note: this error is expected if this SSH key was already registered on your account)"